# Check if app's in foreground or background

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update user status in firestore to online and offline according to whether the app runs in the background or foreground. I'm using **LifecycleObserver** for it, but the **problem is I have to call it in every single activity for it to work**.

Is there a way to do this without having to call it in every activity?

Observer class:

```
class Observer(private val currentUser: User): LifecycleObserver {

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onEnteredForeground() {
        if (!currentUser.isOnline)
            updateStatus(true)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onEnteredBackground() {
        if (currentUser.isOnline) {
            updateStatus(false)
        }
    }

    private fun updateStatus(status: Boolean) {
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("users").document(currentUser!!.uid)
            .update(
                "isOnline", status
            )
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!")
                return@addOnSuccessListener
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(ContentValues.TAG, "Error writing document", e)
                return@addOnFailureListener
            }
    }
}
```

How I call it:

```
lifecycle.addObserver(Observer(user))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.6.0"
}
```

Then in your Application class,add :

```
class ArchLifecycleApp : Application(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super<Application>.onCreate()
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onStop(owner)
        Log.d("MyApp", "App in background")
    }

    override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onStart(owner)
        Log.d("MyApp", "App in foreground")
    }
}
```

update your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<application
    android:name=".ArchLifecycleApp"
    //Your extra code
    ....>
</application>
```

Comment: The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated